The composition of immersions is an immersion on differentiable manifolds
I am trying to show that the composition of two immersions is an immersion. The definition provided by William M. Boothby in "An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry" is:

Definition: $F: N \to M$ is said to be an immersion if $\text{rank}\; F=n=\text{dim}\;N(=m=\text{dim}\;M)$ everywhere.


Definition: The rank of $F$ at $p$ is defined to be the rank of the Jacobian Matrix of $\hat{F} = \psi \circ F \circ \varphi^{-1}: \varphi(U) \to \psi(V)$. Where $U,\varphi$ and $V,\psi$ are coordinate charts of $p$ and $F(p)$ respectively.

My attempt:
Let $F_1: N \to \tilde{N}$ and $F_2:\tilde{N}\to M$ be immersions. Let $G = F_2 \circ F_1$, and suppose that $\text{dim}\;N \leq \text{dim}\;\tilde{N} \leq \text{dim}\;M$.
Then since $F_1$ and $F_2$ are immersions, hence they have constant rank everywhere ($\text{rank}\;F_1 = \tilde{n}$ and $\text{rank}\;F_2 = m$), and in local coordinates we can find:
\begin{align*}
\hat{F_1}(x^1,\dots,x^n) &= (x^1,\dots,x^{\tilde{n}},0,\dots,0)\\
\hat{F_2}(x^1,\dots,x^\tilde{n}) &= (x^1,\dots,x^m,0,\dots,0) \\
\end{align*}
Then $G$ in local coordinates is given by $\hat{G} = \hat{F_2} \circ \hat{F_1} = (x^1,\dots,x^m,0,\dots,0):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^\tilde{n}\to\mathbb{R}^m$, and hence the $\text{rank} \; G = m$ everywhere, so $G$ is also an immersion.
Questions: Is this the right idea, and is it enough to conclude that rank of $G$ must be constant everywhere or is something missing? Is it always possible to choose to work with the functions given in local coordinates instead of the mappings between manifolds?

What are you doing putting “($=m=\dim M$)” in the official definition? The result is immediate from the fact that the composition of injective (linear) maps is injective.

That is how the definition is written in book. Can you please elaborate on the second part, since an immersion is not required to be one to one.

First, for immersion you need $n\le m$, rarely equal. The derivative of the map is injective (that’s the usual phrasing of the definition), and then, by the chain rule, the derivative of the composition is the composition of the derivatives.
